# MongoDB function get firestore data via firebase admin returns wrong snapshot size

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a MongoDB cloud function which should read data from my firestore collection via the firebase admin sdk. I have about 7000 docs in the *trips* collection. If I start the function its returning a different amount of docs every time. Sometimes 15, next time 23 and so on. This is my code:

```
  var admin = require('firebase-admin');

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });

  const db = admin.firestore();
    
  const snapshot = await db
      .collection('trips')
      .limit(30)
      .get();
      
  console.log(snapshot.size);
```

I also checked if its the right project, by whatching the increasing usage on my project whenever I start the function. Any help would be great!

**UPDATE**

I tried the same code as a local node script on my machine. And now it works without any problems. So I assume its a problem with mongodb functions. Maybe the function cancels the execution of the query?

**UPDATE 2**

If I query the count of the documents only, it works too. So I made a query about 10 docs only and it also works! Maybe the execution time is too long for a mongoDB function

Comment: `docs.data().count` ?

Comment: I named it very bad, docs is the fb snapshot (will edit this in the question). It does not have a data() method or field unfortunately